# How to validate certification path against url

Tags: c++, windows, certificate

WARNNING: Total certificate newbie

I have a certificate that is used for server authentication and I want to check if that certificate is validate for the url that the server is publish on.

for example: if the certificate is for *.myserver.com then any url that its host part ends with myserver.com is valid.

What I would like is something like this:

```
bool IsValid(string certificateHash, string url)
```

Is there any sample or api that will give me that?

I'm working on Windows and I have to use the Windows API.

P.S. I'm not interested in checking the validity of the issuer, time stemps, etc, only the *Certification Path* (Not sure I'm using the right term here).

Comment: "then any url that ends with myserver.com is valid" ... you probably mean domain or the host-part of the url?

Comment: @gf right, only the host part of the url

Answer (score 0):

The CN of a certificate says for which Domain the Certificate is valid. It may help you to view a SSL-Certificate in Firefox/IE to guess which field means what. (For example connect to https://cacert.org)

And I thought that a certificate can only match a FQDN (Full Qualified Domain Name) - no wildcards.